# How do i store the user details as session

Tags: java, android, session

Hello i am using dynamodb and i want to know how do i maintain a session when the user logs in.

Following is my login code

```
  Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Users user = mapper.load(Users.class,username);

            System.out.println(user.getPassword());
            System.out.println(username);
            if (user != null && user.getPassword().equals(password)){
                //System.out.println("Correct");
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        setContentView(R.layout.activity_account);
                    }
                });
            }
```

and this is my user class where i set and get all entities

```
public class Users {

private String id;
private String email;
private String username;
private String password;
private String role;


@DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName = "id")
public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "email")
public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}
```

same goes for all other variables as well.

Please look at these codes and tell me how i could store sessions as i want the id of the logged in user.

Comment: Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23024831/android-shared-preferences-example

Comment: Yes, Shared preference would be better for your question, and the above link is nice , Follow it

Answer (score 2):

**V1**

you can use SharedPreferences like below

```
public class Prefs {

public static void putPref(String key, String value, Context context){
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putString(key, value);
    editor.commit();
}

public static String getPref(String key, Context context) {
    SharedPreferences preferences =   PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    return preferences.getString(key, null);
 }
}
```

after you have to store

```
 Prefs.putPref("the key","the value",your context);
```

after to get your stored data

```
   String userId = Prefs.getPref("the key",your context);
```

you can use that where you want in your App .

**V2**

use Gson 
add this to your build.gradle

```
  compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:1.7.2'
```

and convert your user object to json like this

```
 Gson gson = new Gson();

 User user = ...; 
 String json = gson.toJson(user);
```

after store your user

```
 Prefs.putPref("user",json,your context);
```

to get your user

```
 String json = = Prefs.getPref("user",your context);

 User user = null;
 if(json != null)
 user = gson.fromJson(json,User.class);
```

thats all