# How to use session management (using shared preference) in more then one android activity (different activity for different account)

Tags: android, session, android-sharedpreferences

I want to create session management in android for more then one `activity`.

i read session management on this site http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-session-management-using-shared-preferences/

how to create above code for more then one `Activity`? From above tutorial i can understand for one activity only.

Comment: look at my answer [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39125796/how-do-i-store-the-user-details-as-session/39126473#39126473](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39125796/how-do-i-store-the-user-details-as-session/39126473#39126473)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the same logic explained in that link. While using Activities, save the preference data(logged in or not boolean etc) when user leaves or enter the activity class. Like in onPause method.